# What is an Energetic Transmitter Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it an Energetic Transmitter Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

[image: Energetic Transmitter Words]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Energetic Transmitter Words™,Not Energetic Transmitter Words™
AUDIOGRAM,INAUDIBLE
BUCKMINSTERFULLERENE,BUCKY-BALL
COMMUNICABLE,TRANSLATABLE
COMPULSION,OBSESSION
DRAGON,MONSTER
DUMBFOUNDING,BAMBOOZLING
ENTHUSIASM,EAGERNESS
HOMEBUILDER,HOMEMAKER
IMMUNOFLUORESCENCE,EPIFLUORESCENCE 
MICROFAUNA,MACROFAUNA
MOUNTAINEERING,SPELUNKING
TANTALIZES,EXCITES
UNIMAGINATIVENESS,TEDIOUSNESS
IMMUNOTHERAPEUTIC,MICROTRANSPLANTATION
```

Comment: How does one make those aesthetically pleasing charts?!

Comment: @greenturtle3141 I've made mine in Excel, and took a screenshot. Not the most elegant, but it works out nicely.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Mine is from Excel, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think an ETW is one that

> contains the letters of a radioactive element (i.e., one with no stable isotope).

Specifics, which also explain why IMMUNOTHERAPEUTIC is extremely energetic:

> **AUDI**OG**R**A**M**: RADIUM
>  **B**UC**KMI**NSTERF**U**L**LERE**NE: BERKELIUM
>  C**OM**M**UNI**CA**BLE**: NOBELIUM
>  C**OMPUL**S**ION**: POLONIUM
>  **DRA**G**ON**: RADON
>  **DUMB**FO**UN**D**I**NG: DUBNIUM
>  ENT**HUSIASM**: HASSIUM
>  **HOM**E**BUI**LDE**R**: BOHRIUM
>  **IMMU**NO**F**LUO**RE**SCENCE: FERMIUM
>  **MICR**O**FAUN**A: FRANCIUM
>  **MOUNT**A**INEER**IN**G**: ROENTGENIUM
>  **TANTA**L**I**Z**ES**: ASTATINE
>  **UNIM**AG**I**NA**TI**V**ENES**S: EINSTEINIUM
>  **I**M**MU**NOTHE**R**APE**U**TI**C**: CURIUM
>  **I**M**MUN**O**THE**RAP**E**U**T**I**C**: TECHNETIUM
>  **I**M**MUN**OTHER**A**PEU**TIC**: ACTINIUM
>  (and there are, so Engineer Toast assures me and I have no trouble believing, several others that likewise go into IMMUNOTHERAPEUTIC besides those three)

I confess I haven't checked all the non-ETWs.

Comment: Seems too well put together to be wrong. These are getting answered quicker than I can get a chance to look at them!

Comment: Occupational hazard of being in a venue full of clever people. I'm sure everyone here has seen plenty of puzzles come and go before they have a chance to attempt them.

Comment: This is correct and has excellent formatting! Can you find all 11 elements in the last word? (I think it was 11. The file is at work but I remember is was a startlingly large number.)

Comment: I expect I can, but I really don't want to :-).

Comment: But I'll add a remark in the answer to the effect that the three I've given are by no means all of them.

Comment: I mis-remembered. It was only 9: Uranium, Americium, Promethium, Protactinium, Meitnerium, Actinium, Curium, Thorium, Technetium

Comment: That's still an awful lot.